# How to Recover Google Chrome User Settings-windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome

I need to restore my chrome settings to a previous version, as one of my gmail passwords was auto saved and I can't get it back since I 'restarted' the settings.

I've tried going to 'C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome'and right clicking user data to restore to a previous version, but I don't get the previous version tab when I go into properties.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am pretty desperate here.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

These files don't have a version history so restoring an old version is not possible.
Go to Chrome settings, saved passwords and delete the saved GMail password.